# Implementing Google reCaptcha v.2 with Gene_Braintree module

Tags: checkout, security, braintree

Magento version EE 2.3.3-p1.

I was wondering if anyone out there has implemented core Msp_Recaptcha at checkout when using the BrainTree or Gene_BrainTree modules. We've been hit HARD by carding attacks targeted using Magento's guest checkout api and the Braintree module.

The response from both parties is to just add recaptcha to the place order step at checkout. Magento core doesn't have an option to add recaptcha nor does BrainTree's extensions. So I'm having to custom develop this. Was wondering if anyone has done this before and has examples of code on how to do so. I'm getting a little stuck trying to inject it into the BrainTree place order step.

Google reCaptcha (GR) V2 was controlled by core Msp_Recaptcha module, which was part of the core MSP security package.

I used the "Magento_PaypalReCaptcha" module (another M2 core module) as example in this project and was able to render GR widget right under the credit card payment method section, which was populated by the Gene_Braintree module. Here is the checkout_index_index.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="payments-list" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="before-place-order" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="msp_recaptcha" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Sb_CheckoutRecaptcha/js/paypalReCaptcha</item>
                                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">30</item>
                                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">before-place-order</item>
                                                                            <item name="configSource" xsi:type="string">checkoutConfig</item>
                                                                            <item name="reCaptchaId" xsi:type="string">msp-recaptcha-checkout-order-place</item>
                                                                            <item name="zone" xsi:type="string">sb_checkout_order</item>
                                                                            <item name="formId" xsi:type="string">co-transparent-form-braintree</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

I am having problem with validating GR for the credit card payment method at the checkout, both client and server side validation. The server side validation should be done before validating payment method, for example before charging (authorize/capture) the credit card.

Was wondering if someone can guide me on both client and server side validation parts here.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you got any solution for this? How did you able to add recaptcha to braintree for guest checkout?

Comment: @BookReader, did you find any solution this?